# Base/root of increment and decrement

Tags: etymology, morphology

I'm tasked with a morphological analysis of *incrementing*.  I would say that *crement* is the base of *increment* and the root of the word.  But I'm curious, because all my life I've been thinking about the words *increment* and *decrement* differently.<sup>1</sup>

Would the morpheme *crement* be referred to as a "cranberry morpheme" and if so, did it once mean something on its own in English?  I've looked up some etymology, and understand the Latin origin of the words—*incrementum* and *decrementum*.

- Did the words come entirely as units from Latin?  Or did we get the two morphemes in each individually and combine them?
- If they did come as units from Latin, can we still consider *crement* a cranberry morpheme, given that it did not ever exist on its own in English?  Does it even make sense, then, to break it up into *in* + *crement* or is the word atomic?  Can we consider, in morphological analysis, previous versions of words if they are in other languages?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> For some reason, I've always thought of *increment* and *decrement* in the same way as I've thought of *accelerate* and *decelerate* (*accelerate* being a word on its own and *decelerate* being contrived to take away from *accelerate* and "opposite" it).  I suppose I was entirely wrong, as both *incrementum* and *decrementum* existed in Latin, and *crementum* indeed means something.</sup>

Comment: Please also visit [linguistics.se]

Comment: Please show evidence of background research.

Comment: It's borrowed from Latin. The basic verb is [_cresco_](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=cresco&la=la&can=cresco0&prior=crescentia#lexicon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well described question.

I wonder if it would clarify some of your thoughts it you replaced "increment and decrement" with "increase and decrease" and then run through the same questions. (Tim posted his similar thought while I was writing this).

We don't say that the root word there is 'crease'.
What we observe is a side effect of a particular form/tense of a word that also has a prefix. Or we could say it's a word that atomized in English after a root had been both prefixed and suffixed, which obscures the form.

As you observe this **is** similar to what's happening with [accelerate](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=accelerate&allowed_in_frame=0) and decelerate.

[Here is etymology for crew, which demonstrates some interesting relationships.](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=crew&allowed_in_frame=0)

So as you examine "increment and decrement" keep in mind that the root (albeit obscured) is the same as increase, accrue, crescendo, recruit, and create.

Answer (score 2):

Per the MED, we have during the Middle English period the nouns *en|increment* (L. incrementum) and  *incrementacioun* (ML incrementatio) and the verb *in|encresen* (AF encreiss-, encress-, CF encroiss-; L incrēscere.).

Many modern speakers when seeing *in*crease and *de*crease would know that *-crease* is probably meaningful and related to *crescent* and *crescendo*. Whether they would make the morphological leap from *-crease* to *-crement* is doubtful, though Chaucer might have done so. Many modern speakers would have no idea that *crescent* has anything to do with *increase*.

You could probably survey a few hundred randomly chosen speakers and ask them what the opposite of "increment" is, and get close to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Latin origin is the right one, not only for English:

The root appears to be ***[crementum](http://fr.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/crementum)***:

> [increase](http://www.latin-dictionary.org/crementum).

Both ***crementum and increase*** seem to have a common root in:

Crescent:

> - late 14c., "crescent-shaped ornament," from Anglo-French cressaunt, from Old French creissant "crescent of the moon" (12c., Modern French croissant), from Latin crescentum (nominative crescens), present participle of crescere "come forth, spring up, grow, thrive, swell, increase in numbers or strength," ***from PIE root *ker- (3) "to grow" (cognates: Latin Ceres, goddess of agriculture, creare "to bring forth, create, produce;***" Greek kouros "boy," kore "girl;" Armenian serem "bring forth," serim "be born").

Etymology: (increment and decrement)

> - increment (n.) : 
>     mid-15c., "act or process of increasing," ***from Latin incrementum "growth, increase; an addition,***" from stem of increscere "to grow in or upon" (see increase). Meaning "amount of increase" first attested 1630s.
> - decrement (n.) 
>     1620s, ***from Latin decrementum*** "diminution," from stem of decrescere (see decrease). (Etymonline)

[Incrementare](http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=incrementare): (Italian)

> - Etimologia: ← dal lat. tardo incrementāre, deriv. di ***incremĕntum*** ‘aumento’.

- The French *augmenter* and the Spanish *aumentar* are from Latin *augmentare*.

Comment: I am not so much asking about the origin; I'm familiar with the Latin roots.  Look at the two bullet points—those are my questions.